# Hex map equivalent in 3-dimensional space

Tags: geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

In 2-dimensional space, hex maps are great for gaming because any single cell's center is equal distance to any adjacent cell's center, as seen below:

[image]

I am looking to do a 3-dimensional board game in VR and would like to have the cells in the game have that same property. Is there a 3-dimensional shape (or shape with spacers) that can tessellate in a way that can achieve this.

Comment: It's a hexagon because, it makes sense to move in 6 different directions from current position, right? In that case a simple extension can be two hexagonal pyramids joined base to base? That way you can jump either to one of 6 locations above or 6 below.

Comment: You can go with [rhombic dodecahedral packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedral_honeycomb). This is not quite what you want, but pretty close.